# What is the word for "something that you can't get enough of"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider some desirable thing `X`.

What I want to mean: `I can't get enough of X`,

How I want to say it: `X is <foobar>`

Is there any word for `<foobar>`?

The closest word that I know is "irresistible". But I have a limited vocabulary, and probably there is a better word out there.

Comment: Addicting or addictive?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Well, `addictive` is a word with a strong meaning that often overshadows it's other possible meanings. Maybe something else?

Comment: Maybe not *exactly* what you're looking for, but how about [***moreish***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/moreish) *(causing a desire for more)?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, `moreish` is great - but I think it is mainly appropriate in the food context. I'm looking for something more general.

Comment: Peanut butter M&Ms!

Answer (score -1):

**Addictive** ? :
 producing or tending to cause addiction: an addictive drug.
             http://www.thefreedictionary.com/addictive